# Outbound message getting 554 rejecting banned content from Postini

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spam

Setup: In-house Exchange Server 2010 using Postini for spam protection.

An user in our organization is getting his outbound emails to a particular recipient bounced back with an error of "Postini #554 rejecting banned content ##".  I have added that recipient to this user's "Approved Recipient" list to no avail.

I'm looking for advice on how to troubleshoot this issue. At the moment, I can't find any log messages for this particular email.

Comment: What is the "Reporting MTA" on the bounce?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: The returned emails doesn't have the Reporting-MTA header/field.

Comment: That's true, but it is stated in the body and not in the header.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question and include the bounce message, that will give us more information to help you

Answer (score 2):

This is not coming from your end.  It is on the recipients end and they are blocking it.  If it was your end then postini would have -psmtp at the end of the error.  That is why adding it to the approved list did nothing.

You have to  see about them adding the sender to the approved list.

I know this is an old question but it still comes up on Google so I figured I would answer it.